# How to have 2 absolutelayouts that overlay eachother

Tags: xaml, xamarin, layout, absolutelayout

I would like to have 2 absolute layouts that overlay each other. Like having 2 pieces of glass on top of each other where each overlay can have it's own controls and behavior. One absolute layout doesn't work for me because I want each glass (per say) to have it's own behaviors for sizing and such. Xaml is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do this is to enclose both absolute layouts in a parent absolute layout. Zorder becomes important for touch and gestures

Answer (score 0):

What about 2 page on top of eachother where the page on top has transparant background where you can click through?

I have never tried it out but I think it might be possible with this package:
https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Good luck!